# How can I rank up weapons in the single player campaign?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I'm trying to upgrade my Avenger rifle from Rank 1 to Rank 2 and I have no idea what to do. I thought it would be in the research/development section but it's not and I don't know if I need to find a blueprint or what.

How can I rank up weapons in the single player campaign?

Answer (score 5):

In order to upgrade a weapon you need to research it. Go to the research section and select the type of weapon you want from the 3 research points.

Then go to the weapons area and select the type of weapon you want to research. There you will see all of the weapons that you can research.

After selecting it, you can then choose to research the level I of that weapon, or continue to enhance it by going to II or III depending on what you have already done. After researching it, exit and go to development.

Here, you have to have the correct materials to build it. After building it, it will then appear in your inventory.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that was just for multiplayer....my headaches begin.

Answer (score 1):

Weapon level is locked by either Research Level or player level. In the case of weapons that can be researched in the Research terminal, you can only build up to the highest level you have unlocked.

For weapons that are unlocked by default, you can build the next tier up every time you reach a level threshold, which are the same thresholds that unlock the next tier of research upgrades.

For example, when I started, I could only build an Avenger 1. When I reached level 6, I was then able to build an Avenger 2. However, if I wanted to build a Widow 2, I'd have to research level 1 and 2 of the Widow and be level 6 or above.